# Vue 3 - $attrs Volar complaining TypeScript Error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to use $attrs on my BaseInput component but the "type" property Volar is complaining about. How do I use $attrs in the right way?

My Component:

```
<template>
    <label class="label">{{ label }}</label>
    <input
        v-bind="$attrs"
        class="input"
        :value="modelValue"
        @input="$emit('update:modelValue', handleInputChange($event))"
    >

    <span class="v" v-if="vMessage.length > 0">
        <span class="v--error">{{ vMessage[0] }}</span>
    </span>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

    export default defineComponent({
        inheritAttrs: false,
        props: {

            label: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            modelValue: {
                type: [String, Number],
                default: ''
            },
            vMessage: {
                type: Array,
                default: []
            }
        },
        setup() {
            const handleInputChange = (event: Event) => (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value

            return { handleInputChange }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Usage:

```
        <BaseInput
            v-model="object_number"
            type="text" <!-- ERROR HERE
            label="Objektnummer"
            class="input--small"
        />
```

Error:

Type '{ modelValue: any; type: string; label: string; class: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Partial<{ modelValue: string | number; label: string; vMessage: unknown[]; }>

Comment: I cannot reproduce that Volar error. Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: See https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1387
https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1077#issuecomment-1146584565